# Jenkins - How to send multipart form data for large file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multipartform-data

I was previously uploading files with `httpRequest` but now I need to include more fields in the `multipart/form-data` request.

I can't use `readFile` for accessing the file since it's too large and causes an `OutOfMemoryError`. Is there any way of obtaining a `FileInputStream` so I can create a `MultipartRequestEntity`?

Or, is there a way of using `httpRequest` with the `uploadFile` parameter AND specify extra fields.

Comment: Provided your file is on disk, why don't you use `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: you can use golang, and directly stream your file, without buffering. I think java supports it too...